# How do I permanently select a line with the click event in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I have multi-line graph where I want to click on a line and permanently highlighted it. I am using the following code with the click event, however after I click and move the mouse, the line goes back.

Hope someone could help me!

*EDIT:* I also have a mouseover and mouseout event that I included in the code snippet.

```
diagam.on('click', countryClick)
      .on('mouseover, countryOver)
      .on('mouseout, countryOut);

  //Mouse event functions
        function countryOver(event, d) {
            d3.select(this)
                .style('stroke', 'black')
                .style('stroke-width', 5)
                .attr('id', 'countryOver')
            .selectAll('g')
                .append('text')
                .attr('class', 'tile-text')
                .attr('x', x(dataByCountry.year) / 2)
                .attr('y', y(dataByCountry) / 2)
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('font-size', '50')
                .attr('fill', 'black')
                .text(dataByCountry.name);

        }

        function countryOut(event, ) { 
            d3.select(this)
                .style('stroke', 'green')
                .style('stroke-width', 1.5)
            .selectAll('g')
                .append('text')
                .attr('class', 'tile-text')
                .attr('x', x(dataByCountry.year) / 2)
                .attr('y', y(dataByCountry) / 2)
                .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
                .attr('font-size', '50')
                .attr('fill', 'black')
                .text(dataByCountry.name)
        }

        function countryClick(event, d){
            d3.select(this)
            .style('stroke', 'red')
            .style('stroke-width', 7)
        .selectAll('g')
            .append('text')
            .attr('class', 'tile-text')
            .attr('x', x(dataByCountry.year) / 2)
            .attr('y', y(dataByCountry) / 2)
            .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
            .attr('font-size', '50')
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .text(dataByCountry.name)
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a function called on mouseOut too ?

Comment: Yes, I do. Is this why the click is not permanent?

Comment: It depends what you do in this function. Could you share it ? Check if you don't change the color of the line somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I did change the code snippet above. I do have a mouseout and mouseover event as well that highlight a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to highlight the line when the mouse is over it and also change its color when you click on it, you can use CSS to style the path depending on its state.

Take a look at this example: https://codepen.io/ccasenove/pen/zYaoGpN

Initially the paths only have the class `line` so we can select them using d3, and the color is set to black in CSS. On mouseover, the class `over` is set on the element which turns it green because of the CSS rule. On mouseout, the class `over` is removed. And when the path is clicked, the class `selected` is set to change the color to red.